# C# генерация кода на этапе компиляции

Tags: c#, nuget

Добрый день,

хочу написать Nuget плагин для авто-генерации кода в проектах с mvvmcross на основе атрибутов.

Идея в том, что при добавлении собственного атрибута к свойству

```
[MyBinding]
public int Test {get; set;}
```

Будет генерироваться код

```
private int _test;

public int Test 
{
  get=> return _test; 
  set
  {
    _test = value;
    TestChanged();
  }
}

public event Action TestChanged = delegade{};
```

Создаваться новый класс

```
public class TestCustomBinding{}
```

и переписываться(дополняться)  метод в файле Setup.cs

```
protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
{
    registry.TestCustomBinding; //новая строка

    base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
}
```

Есть идеи как это все правильно реализовать?
Спасибо.

Comment: посмотрите как реализовано в [Fody/PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged)

Comment: в этом направлении и смотрю, но тут сейчас реализации через интерфейс и следовательно ко всему классу. Это-то наверное не будет проблемой переделать? 
А вот переписать метод теории мне не хватает.

Comment: Вы хотите реально посткомпиляционую обработку наподобие PostSharp, или кодогенерацию перед компиляцией? Если второе, вам придётся подождать версии языка с replace/original (https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/107)

Comment: Ну или освоить ручную кодогенерацию через T4.

Comment: Ждать можно, но видимо придется на первом этапе кодогенерацию внедрять, так как как кода будет не много и просто регистрация новых, заранее известных параметров